# What libraries are required for Facebook Audience Network on Android?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, facebook-audience-network

I'm using Android facebook sdk 4.20.0.
The `R.txt` file contains 1500 entries, most of them referring to `android-support-v7-appcompat` library.

Is `appcompat` required in order to show facebook ads?

I didn't find it in [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android).